# Angular - running functions from controller on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to run some function on load of a directive, and then be able to "rerun" it again with `ng-click`. My code is as follows:

```
const app = angular.module('app', []);

class dummyController {
    logIt() {
        console.log('logging');
    }
}

app.directive('dummyDir', () => {
    return {
        controller: dummyController,
        link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.logIt = ctrl.logIt();
            scope.logIt;

        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <button class="reinit" type="submit" dummy-dir ng-click="logIt()">Reinit</button>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/VejZqV?editors=101)

Unfortunately, clicking the button does nothing. What have I done wrong?

Comment: If you call the logit() from within the controller, you don't need to call it from link. Doing that will call the log it() twice. The reason is that controller gets instanciated before link and also runs any logit() when controller is invoked. So invoke logit() from controller, make a different function that will run logit() invokation from ng-click

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line

```
scope.logIt = ctrl.logIt();
```

you are actually invoking the `logIt` function and assigning the result of this function to variable `logIt`. The function does not return anything, so the result is undefined.

Instead you need to assign variable a pointer to a function, so you can use it later:

```
link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
    scope.logIt = ctrl.logIt;    // assign a function, do not invoke it
    scope.logIt();               // invoke the function
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class dummyController {
    logIt() {
        console.log('logging');
    }
    logIt();

}
```